# Git diff filenames breaking consistency

Tags: git, diff, filenames, git-diff

This line was taken from a raw diff consisting of 2852 file changes (switched multiple libraries).

```
diff --git "a/system/cms/config/database.php\n" "b/system/cms/config/database.php\n"
```

Out of all 2852 file changes, this is the only diff in which the filenames are enclosed in quotes and terminated with "\n". Every other related line fits this pattern.

```
diff --git a/system/cms/config/constants.php b/system/cms/config/constants.php
```

Any idea as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because you actually have a filename that contains a `\n` at the end of it.

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/foo/tmp/.git/
$ echo foo > a$'\n'
$ git add a*
$ git commit -m one
[master (root-commit) 2ce40fd] one
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 "a\n"
$ echo bar >> a*
$ git diff|less
diff --git "a/a\n" "b/a\n"
index 257cc56..3bd1f0e 100644
--- "a/a\n"
+++ "b/a\n"
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 foo
+bar
```